# Open folder from list in Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This code is used to open a specific folder.

```
Dim strFolderPath As String 
strFolderPath = “C:\temp\” 
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (strFolderPath)
```

I need to open a folder saved in an Excel sheet (like in the image below). I need to read the path in Excel and to open the folder.

[image]

Comment: in which column do you store path ? do you want to open all folder in the same time ?

Comment: Column Path
no i just need to click on button Open Folder 
To Open C:\Photo\John_1_1

Comment: Whats the name of your column Path ? "A" "B" "C" "D"  and so on

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your table in the first three columns from A to C. You can write your serial number in cell E1 and run macro. For example, if you enter 3 in cell E1 and click the button, the folder from Edres will be open.

```
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim NrRow As Long
NrRow = Cells(1, 5)
strFolderPath = Cells(NrRow + 1, 3).Value
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (strFolderPath)
```